# How do I coalesce processing of related events in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I have a situation where I have a service subscribing to event messages and performing some work when they arrive.  There is a certain class of events which can arrive in short bursts of many events which reference the same underlying data.  I would like to be able to defer processing of related events for a short period of time, so that I only do the calculation once for each batch of related events, rather than in response to each individual event.  Is there some kind of pattern I can follow which will allow me to collect related events for a period of time and then process them all at once?  I was thinking a saga + timeout might be able to achieve this, but not sure if this is an appropriate use for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a saga could be the way to go - however consider the performance of the saga persistence (NHibernate over a DB in the current version, RavenDB in the next version) as compared to your fault-tolerance needs (if a machine crashes, would it be acceptable to lose some messages).

No easy answers, I'm afraid.